# Fill missing gaps in date range query using calendar table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the below query to pull back the total product price for a date range, however on the days that no sales where made, i'd like to still show the date but with a value of 0.

I've created a calendar table with a large date range, but haven't been able to work out the best way to do it, everything i'm doing just misses out the days with no sales.

Below is the query i'm using (Without the calendar table):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.purchase_date, '%d %b %Y') as date, sum(price) as price 
    FROM order_products a 
    INNER JOIN order_saved b 
         ON a.order_id = b.id 
    WHERE b.purchase_date
         BETWEEN '2011-09-16 23:59' AND '2011-10-16 23:59' 
    AND b.status > 2
    AND a.usr_id = 'XXXX'
    GROUP BY DAY(b.purchase_date)
    ORDER BY b.purchase_date ASC
```

The calendar table i've tried with just contains a list of date ranges starting from 2010-01-01 up to 2014-12-30 (calendar.date is the table.row)

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: many times I had the same problem, not just with the date... I concluded that it's nasty to do it in the database and I did it in the presentation layer (in PHP in my case). But it's a good question indeed.

Comment: maybe you should add those values in php so that you don't complicate the query too much

Comment: @mishu, that's exactly what I mean :-)

Comment: If you've got any tips in how to do it in PHP that'll be great, i'm only a junior ;)

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274777/how-to-get-values-for-every-day-in-a-month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an outer join on the calendar table. Something like

```
SELECT c.cal_date, coalesce(t1.price, 0) as total
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.purchase_date::date, sum(price) as price 
           FROM order_products a 
           INNER JOIN order_saved b 
                   ON a.order_id = b.id 
                   AND b.purchase_date BETWEEN '2011-09-16 23:59' AND '2011-10-16 23:59' 
                   AND b.status > 2
                   AND a.usr_id = 'XXXX'
            GROUP BY b.purchase_date) t1 on t1.purchase_date = c.cal_date
WHERE cal_date BETWEEN '2011-09-16 23:59' AND '2011-10-16 23:59' 
ORDER BY c.cal_date
```

You'll get better answers if you post the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements, and minimal `INSERT` statements that give us enough data to actually test our answers. (Edit your question and paste the DDL and INSERT statements.)

Comment: Very well cause it is php(language) independed! Yes create table is so helpful and unfortunately most times not given.

Comment: Amazing, this done the trick! Had to move a few bits around. Thank you so much Catcall!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help, instead of epxlaining here have placed comment where needed. It takes an array (suppose it comes from db) and replaces the missing dates:

```
<?php 
$sales=Array('2011-09-16 23:59'=>2,'2011-09-17 23:59'=>7,
'2011-09-18 23:59'=>7,'2011-09-19 23:59'=>7,'2011-09-20 23:59'=>7,
'2011-09-21 23:59'=>7,'2011-09-22 23:59'=>7,'2011-09-23 23:59'=>1,
'2011-10-05 23:59'=>4,'2011-10-21 23:59'=>16,'2012-04-22 23:59'=>12);
$no_sale=' | <font color=red>0</font><br>'; 

//initialize the previosly printed date to the previous of the very first date in $sales
$last_printed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(substr(key($sales),0,10) . " -1 Day")) ;

foreach($sales as $cd => $sales_cnt)
{
  //extract current date    
  $cd = substr($cd,0,10); 
  //get the next day of the last date that was echoed
  $next_of_last_printed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($last_printed . " +1 Day"));

  //if the current date retrieved from database is next of the last printed
  if($next_of_last_printed  == $cd) 
  {
    echo $cd.' | ', $sales_cnt,'<br>';//then print it
    $last_printed=$cd;//since we print it change the last printed
  }//if
  else
  {     //since current retrieved from db is not valid print a valid date 
        echo $next_of_last_printed ,$no_sale;
        $last_printed = $next_of_last_printed;//since we printed a date set last printed
        while(true)
        {   
            //since we set the last printed then get the next of it
            $next_of_last_printed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($last_printed . " +1 Day"));
            //if the next we generated is the same with the one retrieved from db
             if($next_of_last_printed ==$cd)  
             {
                echo $cd.' | ', $sales_cnt,'<br>';//then echo this retrieved from db
                $last_printed = $cd;//since we printed a date set last printed  
                break(1);
             }
            //since we got the next date print it  
            echo $next_of_last_printed,$no_sale;
            $last_printed = $next_of_last_printed; //then set last printed

        }//while
    }//else 
}//foreach

?>
```