# Combine found results and not found results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have a table that has the information about a log, to know how many hits there were on the pages of the website.

This is the query that shows me the above:

```
select pageview_page, DATE(pageview_date) as pageview_date, count(*) as view_count
     from pageviews
      group by pageviews.pageview_page, DAY(pageviews.pageview_date)
      order by pageviews.pageview_date desc
```

Resulting in the following:

```
Page    Day        view_count
index   2016-01-12 50
index   2016-01-11 10
index   2016-01-10 20
contact 2016-01-12 5
contact 2016-01-11 5
```

**PD**: using `desc` on date because the chart must start on the latest date.

**Notice:** in the above table, `contact` is not present on day `2016-01-10`, meaning no one used that page on that day.

**I want to get the query to show `0` if there is nothing on that date, how can I achieve that?** The result must be like the following

```
Page    Day        view_count
index   2016-01-12 50
index   2016-01-11 10
index   2016-01-10 20
contact 2016-01-12 5
contact 2016-01-11 5
contact 2016-01-10 0 <-------- (I want this to appear, as it is missing in the table above, in the first table)
```

Lets take the next 3 dates as an example: 2016-01-10, 2016-01-11, 2016-01-12

The point is to view the statistics by day, I use the next to get the dates above:

```
select DATE(pageview_date) as pageview_date from pageviews GROUP by DAY(pageview_date)
```

I have tried a combination with `IN` and `NOT IN` with the query above but I cant get it working.

Comment: @RyanVincent yea, but I already have the days, in the query above. I just tried that and doesnt seem to work, i dont get any value in return.

Comment: @RyanVincent select DATE(pageview_date) as pageview_date from pageviews GROUP by DAY(pageview_date) there are all the dates i need

Comment: maybe interesting? http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/displaying-missing-dates-by-utilizing/.  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796401/fill-missing-gaps-in-date-range-query-using-calendar-table?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `DAY` function in MySQL but by looking your first query I think you can do something like this -

```
select T2.pageview_page AS pageview_page,
       T1.pageview_date AS pageview_date,
       (select count(*)
          from pageviews t3
         where t3.pageview = t2.pageview
           and DAY(t3.pageview_date) = t1.pageview_date) as view_count
  from (select distinct DAY(pageview_date) pageview_date FROM pageviews) t1,
       (SELECT DISTINCT pageview_page FROM pageviews) t2
 group by pageview_page, pageview_date
 order by pageview_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of days (or integers) and do a `LEFT JOIN` from it to your query:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM AllDays a
    LEFT JOIN ( your query ) b ON b.date = a.date
    WHERE a.date BETWEEN ...;
```

Even better would be to use a MariaDB "sequence table".