# Getting UNIX TIME with number

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT  c.day,
        COUNT(site_id)
FROM    calendar c
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM   visitors
            WHERE  site_id = 16
        ) d ON  DAYOFMONTH(d.created) = c.day
WHERE c.day BETWEEN DAYOFMONTH('2012-10-01') AND DAYOFMONTH('2012-10-31')
GROUP BY c.day
ORDER BY c.day
```

My Tables

```
Calendar

id  | day
---------
1   | 1
2   | 2
3   | 3
...
31  | 31

Visitors

id  | site_id | created
-----------------------------------
1   | 16      | 2012-10-18 11:14:39
2   | 16      | 2012-10-18 11:15:17
3   | 11      | 2012-10-18 11:49:14
4   | 11      | 2012-10-18 11:49:43
5   | 16      | 2012-10-19 11:54:37
6   | 1       | 2012-10-19 05:56:31
7   | 2       | 2012-10-19 05:57:56
```

I used the above query to retrieve a daily result of visits to a site. The query solved my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003572/getting-data-for-every-single-day-in-sql).

Results:

```
day | COUNT(*)
-------------
1   |       0
2   |       0
3   |       0
....
18  |       2
19  |       1
...
31  |       0
```

Although, now, I am having problems retrieving UNIX_TIMESTAMP from the `day` which I need for graphing purposes.

How do I retrieve it from the `c.day` in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited:*

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-01' + INTERVAL c.day - 1 DAY) unix_ts_day,
  COUNT(v.site_id)
FROM
  calendar c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM visitors
    WHERE site_id = 16 AND DATE(created) BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-31'
  ) v
  ON DAYOFMONTH(v.created) = c.day
GROUP BY
  unix_ts_day
```

Comment: v.created is NULL on most days. For example, v.created will be NULL on the first row. `1 | 0 | NULL` since it is a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I need to get all days of the month. starting from the first day to the last day. which means I need 31 rows everytime.